# How to filter datagridview by string in textbox in visual basic without using SQL query WHERE?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to filter rows of datagridview based on textBox value. I want to remove all rows which don't have values like in column NAZIV. I'm new in visual basic.

Name of datagridView is dvgIQ

I've tried this but it's not working.

```
    Sub filter
      If textBox1.Text.Length>=3 Then
        For i As Integer = dvgIQ.Count-1  To 0 Step -1
          If Not dvgIQ.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString(textBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
            dvgIQ.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
          End If
        Next i
      Else If textBox1.Text.Length>0 And textBox1.Text.Length<3 Then
            MsgBox("warning")
      End If
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Base on the DGV layout, `NAZIV` is Column `3`, not `4` (`[Row].Cells(3)`). Indexing starts from `0`. You should filter the DGV's DataSource, not remove rows from the Control. Specify what is the DataSource of your DGV.

Comment: I've changed that, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Changed what? Are you filtering the DataSource? Or are you still using `If Not dvgIQ.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString(textBox1.Text.ToLower) Then ... ` which doesn't mean anything? Maybe `If Not dvgIQ.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then ... ` (Or `.Value.ToString().IndexOf(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0`, if you're looking for a substring)

Comment: I have this error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I've added      If Not    (dvgIQ.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString.Contains(textBox1.Text.ToString))

Comment: I don't know how to filtering with DataSource.

Comment: Probably `Rows(i)` doesn't exist (you're including the `NewRow` object in your loop). What is the DataSource of your DGV? If it's a DataTable, the you can write something like: `DirectCast(dvgIQ.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = $"NAZIV LIKE '%{textBox1.Text}%'"` (if the Column name is actually `NAZIV`). Otherwise, you can use LINQ to filter a `List(Of Something)`. Or use a BindingSource (good in both cases).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211314/discussion-between-robhellford-and-jimi).

Answer (score 0):

You should start by populating a `DataTable` with your data. If the data comes from a database then use a data adapter and call its `Fill` method or else use a data reader and call `Load` on the `DataTable`. If the data is not from a database then you can build and populate the `DataTable` manually.

Next, bind the `Datatable` to a `BindingSource` that you added to the form in the designer. Finally, bind the `BindingSource` to your grid:

```vb
BindingSource1.DataSource = myDataTable
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

To filter the grid, you simply set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`, e.g.

```vb
BindingSource1.Filter = $"SomeColumn LIKE '{TextBox1.Text}%'"
```

That will exclude all rows where `SomeColumn` does not start with the text in `TextBox1`. You should read the documentation for the [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_BindingSource_Filter) property and follow the specified link to learn what syntax is supported by ADO.NET. It is a small subset of SQL.